# VBA PowerPoint - Restricting macro only for specific slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to implement a error handling to my PowerPoint macro that restricts you to run the macro unless you are on slide 5. I am trying to utilize the command: "Application.ActiveWindow.View <> 5 Then" but it does not seem to recognize I am on slide 5, what is the correct comand for it ?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Sld As Slide
    Dim Shp As Shape

    'ERROR HANDLING
        If ActivePresentation.Slides.Count < 5 Then
            MsgBox "You do not have any slides in your PowerPoint project."
            Exit Sub
        End If

    Set Sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide

        If activeSlide <> 5 Then
            MsgBox "You are not on the correct slide."
            Exit Sub
        End If

    Set Sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
End Sub
```

Comment: You already captured `Sld`.  Could you not say something like `If Sld.Number <> 5 Then`?  Also, the second `Set Sld` is not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**activeSlide** is not a PowerPoint object and you haven't defined it as anything else, replace it with **Sld** and add **SlideIndex** to get the number:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Sld As Slide
    Dim Shp As Shape

    'ERROR HANDLING
        If ActivePresentation.Slides.Count < 5 Then
            MsgBox "You do not have any slides in your PowerPoint project."
            Exit Sub
        End If

    Set Sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide

        If Sld.SlideIndex <> 5 Then
            MsgBox "You are not on the correct slide."
            Exit Sub
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was exactly what I was looking for !